# Count the number trailing blank space in a string

Tags: c++, string

Can anyone help me in decreasing the complexity of the code below which counts the number of trailing blank spaces in a string.

```
void main()
{
    string url = "abcd   ";
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++)
    {
        if (url.at(i) == ' ')
        {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < url.length(); k++)
            {
                if (url.at(k) != ' ')
                {
                    count = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
cout<< count;
}
```

Comment: If your code is working proprly, and you want your code to be reviewed, maybe the best suited place is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Thank You.

Comment: by the cout it is clearly known that, it is a c++ program.  why the `c` tag???

Comment: Take one integer variable for url length, dont use `url.length();` in for loop.

Comment: @Himanshu No, it is way better to USE `.length()`. It makes code clear and easy to read. And I'm sure all modern compilers can optimize such things.

Comment: one loop shall be enough; count it by iterating the characters from the last character of the string (right to the left) and break when you find a non-space character.

Comment: @sharon : C tag removed. Its more like a general question that is why I  had tagged C. Nevermind.

Comment: @Satus Want to make code more readable or more efficient. `url.length();` will count length again and again for every value, which is of no use.

Comment: Why do you compare aginst the character constant `' '` in one place, and the hard-coded ASCII value 32 in another place?

Comment: @Kaz: You have got a point.. :)

Comment: @Himanshu `std::string::length()` has `O(1)` complexity -- it literally just reads a data field. It does not "count" anything. You may be thinking of `strlen()`.

Comment: @user1292432, why dont you try to count from last index of the string(in reverse order)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start backward counting the white space

```
void main() {
    string url = "abcd   ";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = url.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        if (url.at(i) == ' ') {
            count++;                
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
cout<< count;
}
```

Comment: I think, it should have to be `int i = url.length()-1; i >= 0;`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string url = "abcd    "; // four spaces
  string rev = url;

  reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());

  cout << "There are " << strspn(rev.c_str(), " ") << " trailing spaces." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

We can do this without reversing the string, and without using a C function like `strspn`. For example, look up the `string::find_last_not_of` function. It will find the last character in the string which is not in the specified set, and return its position.  If your set is the set `" "` (space) then it finds the last non-space character. The difference between that position and the string length is the count of trailing spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string url = "abcd    "; // four spaces
  size_t last_nonspace = url.find_last_not_of(" ");
  cout << "There are " << url.length() - last_nonspace - 1 << " trailing spaces." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that if there is no non-space character in the string (the string is either empty or contains only spaces), the `find_last_not_of` function returns `string::npos` which is just `(size_t) -1`, the largest value of `size_t`. When this is subtracted from the length, and then 1 is subtracted, the resulting value is just the length. The arithmetic works out in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the find_if() algorithm function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "This string has spaces at the end    ";
    string::iterator it = 
         find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](char ch) { return !isspace(ch); }).base();
    cout << "The number of trailing spaces is " << std::distance(it, s.end());
}
```

Basically we start from the end of the string, and let find_if() find the first non-space character (I used `isspace` instead of the hard-coded 32).

After that, the iterator that is returned will point to the non-space character, so it's a matter of just knowing the "distance" between that point and the end (that is what `std::distance` will do for us).